# MVC/Razor : Conditional nested html tag

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'd like to have this html code where a condition ("myBool") is true :

```
<div>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>
      @sometext
    </legend>
    ... other stuffs
  </fieldset>
<div>
```

and this one when it's false :

```
<div>
  <b>
    @sometext
  </b>
  ... other stuffs
<div>
```

I dont what to whave to write se same code ("other stuffs") twice so I tried this :

```
<div>
@if(myBool)
{
  <fieldset>
    <legend>
}
else
{
  <b>
}
@sometext
if (myBool)
{
  </legend>
}
else
{
  </b>
}
...other stuff
if (myBool)
{
  </fieldset>
}
</div>
```

but I get compilation errors.

Do you see how I could do what I want without having to do somethig like that :

```
@if(myBool)
{
  <div>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>
        @sometext
      </legend>
      ... other stuffs
    </fieldset>
  <div>
}
else
{
  <div>
    <b>
      @sometext
    </b>
    ... other stuffs
  <div>
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The following might work using the `@:` operator.
When you're inside a code block, either because of a control structure (like in the example given below) or because you have explicitly defined one, you can output plain text by prefixing with a @-character followed by a : (colon) character.

```
<div>
    @if (someCondition)
    {
        @:<fieldset>
            @:<legend>
    }
    else
    {
        @:<b>
    }

    @sometext

    if (someCondition)
    {
        @:</legend>
    }
    else
    {
        @:</b>
    }

    ... other stuffs

    @if (someCondition)
    {
        @:</fieldset>
    }
</div>
```

or you might also try the following:

```
<div>
    @Html.Raw(someCondition ? "<fieldset><legend>" : "<b>")
    @sometext
    @Html.Raw(someCondition ? "</legend>" : "</b>")

    ... other stuffs  

    @if (someCondition)
    {
        @:</fieldset>
    }  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks I didn't knew the @: operator !

Comment: Worked perfectly for me as well. Thanks!

Comment: I really appreciate you Darin, You'r my hero :) Saved my day, if I could I wish point +10, and one question: Is any different between @: and @Html.Raw() ?